# How to compare fields from two databases where one has variable name?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I need to return a field `CreditAdvisor_PrimaryCode` from a database `DWH_Staging` where a field `CooperationEndDate` from the database `DWH_Staging` does not matvh a field `DatumUkonceni` from a database with variable name. We have a procedure `adm.MaxBatch` returning actual name of the database with variable name. I a SP as follows:

```
DECLARE @db_is NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @string NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @db_is = (
        SELECT mb.DatabaseName
        FROM adm.MaxBatch mb
        WHERE mb.SourceID = 1
        )
SET @string = 'SELECT 
               ca.CreditAdvisorCode_Primary 
               FROM ' + @db_is + '..CS_Prodejci prod 
               JOIN ' + @db_is + '..CS_OZ oz ON prod.RC = oz.OZ_RC
               JOIN DWH_Staging.dim.CreditAdvisor ca ON oz.KodOZ = ca.CreditAdvisorCode_Primary
               WHERE prod.KonecCinnosti <> ca.CooperationEndDateId'

PRINT @string

EXEC (@string)
```

which returns only a text output.
Any help would be aprreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It shouldn't just return a text output, it is printing the T-SQL to the message window, but is then executing it, so it should return the results, but presumably it is not doing so? Are the columns CreditAdvisor_PrimaryCode and CreditAdvisorCode_Primary the same thing?

Comment: There's just CreditAdvisorCode_Primary and it should be correct.

Comment: I cannot see anything wrong with the code, it should be executing and would give you an error if the dynamic sql resolved incorrectly etc. If you copy the print output and run it does it return the expected results?

Comment: "which returns only a text output"...What is the text output?

Comment: There was one error I omitted to include a prefix before table names. However, it now returns "Could not find server 'S01_20170904' in sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers." while I see the database in Object Explorer as shown on a printscreen I uploaded here: https://imgur.com/a/wSgEI

Comment: @StanislavJirák take a print of the output of your SQL and post it. The format is [Server].[Database].[Schema].[Table] so at a guess, something must be in an incorrect format so that it thinks S01_20170904 is a server. That said, I cannot see it in your print screen?

Comment: Ups, sorry, appereatly moved the scroll button before the printscreen...here it is: https://imgur.com/a/nfP5A

Comment: @StanislavJirák thats fair, as I said you will want to look at the formatting of your SQL query as it thinks it is a server, use PRINT to print it to the message window as you have in your previous query, so you can see what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

If you would try:

```
DECLARE @db_is NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @string NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @db_is = N'S01_20170904'

/*= (
        SELECT mb.DatabaseName
        FROM adm.MaxBatch mb
        WHERE mb.SourceID = 1
        )
*/

SET @string = N'SELECT 
               ca.CreditAdvisorCode_Primary 
               FROM [' + @db_is + ']..[CS_Prodejci] prod 
               JOIN [' + @db_is + ']..[CS_OZ] oz ON prod.RC = oz.OZ_RC
               JOIN DWH_Staging.dim.CreditAdvisor ca ON oz.KodOZ = ca.CreditAdvisorCode_Primary
               WHERE prod.KonecCinnosti <> ca.CooperationEndDateId'

EXEC sp_executesql @string
```

Does it work for you?